# How can I set the dimensions (specifically width) of TextField in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

As the titles suggests. I'm quite new to JavaFX so it's a bit confusing but I'm trying to set the max width of a TextField. I tried the maxWidth() method but it does not seem to work. This is the relevant code.

```
    TextField field = new TextField("Enter");
    field.maxWidth(300);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(field);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: The method is `Region.setMaxWidth(double)` which sets the `IntegerProperty` returned by the `Region.maxWidthProperty()` method. A `TextField` inherits from [`Region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html). `Region` also has a `prefWidth` and `minWidth` property (with the corresponding height properties).

Comment: `Node.maxWidth` is the method that is used during layout for computing the max width of the node (e.g. if a layout needs the value). It does not set the value of the `maxWidth` property.

Comment: @Abby may I ask why the answer was suddenly unaccepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
field.setMaxWidth(300);
```

For more info refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setMaxWidth-double-).